# Как в массив C вставить числа из массива A, которых нет в массиве B?

Tags: c++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в массив C вставить числа из массива A, которых нет в массиве B?
Нужен такой результат:

```
Массив A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Массив B = [2, 3, 5, 6, 7]

Массив C = [1, 4]
```

Только сделать это нужно без специальных функций, т.е. "в ручную". Мы в институте просто еще не изучали никакие специальные функции, которые могут это делать (если они есть вообще)

UPD:
Вот код, который я пробовал написать

```
void copyc(int a[], int b[], int c[], int n) {
    int i, j, g = 0, tmp = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[i] != b[j]) {
                c[g] = a[i];
                g++;
                break;
            }
            else
                break;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Как жаль, что вы не попытались ничего сделать самостоятельно...

Comment: Очевидно же, надо поискать числа из A в B. Если число там не удалось найти, то надо записать его в C

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В принципе, данное задание можно без проблем продумать самому. Вот Вам рабочий пример, если ещё кто-то не подсказал Вам другой или сами всё же не сделали.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int A[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    int B[] = { 2, 3, 5, 6, 7 };

    int C[size(A)] = {};
    int cSize = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size(A); i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size(B); j++) {
            if (A[i] != B[j]) {
                count++;
            }
            if (count == size(B)) {
                C[cSize] = A[i];
                cSize++;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i : C) {
        if(i!=0)
        cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

Получилось, возможно, достаточно колхозно, но работает, и для примера Вам в самый раз.

Comment: Спасибо, код работает. Выручили)